# PlayReady SME parameters on GoogleCast

Tags: google-cast

1. When using encrypted media extensions on GoogleCast, from the example code here (section 8.4)

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html#examples:

what should be specified for PlayReady in:

```
video.setMediaKeys(new MediaKeys(keySystem));
```

as a keySystem?

2. In the same function, there is initData var (event.initData) in  function `handleKeyNeeded(event)`.  If it is extended by adding custom data, will it be preserved by the DRM engine while license request generating and if not, how to workaround it?

Comment: This is currently being worked on and should be available with the final SDK release.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first question:

```
video.setMediaKeys(new MediaKeys("com.microsoft.playready"));
```

However it would be prudent to query the what systems are supported for given media types using iTypeSupported as per:

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html#dom-istypesupported

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my case 'com.microsoft.playready' did not work, but 'com.youtube.playready' did.